# how to test django project on dotcloud without sandbox

Tags: django, dotcloud

I am developing a django project and I was going to deploy it on dotcloud. But I just noticed they just shut down the sandbox because they are going to open source it.
So how can I test my django project on dotcloud without the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

dotCloud bills on an hourly basis, so you can spin up a live service and test, then destroy the application, paying only for the time you were running the application.

If you have data that you would like to keep from test to test, you can either back it up and restore it, or you can selectively destroy your non-database services (saving RAM and $$$):

```
dotcloud destroy myservice
```

where *myservice* is the name of the non-database service you don't need to persist. When you push again, the destroyed services will be recreated (assuming they're still in your `dotcloud.yml`)